# Passing a jquery variable to vue js

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I have this code that posts some data to a remote server and receives the success message. I am getting an array and I am using that array to contain various pieces of data. I want to use a particular piece of data to show if the direction of a trade is up or is down using Vue.js.

This is the jQuery code:

```
var email = window.localStorage.getItem("email");
     var rid = window.localStorage.getItem("rid");
        var ob = {
      'email' : email,
       'id' : rid
       };

    var data = decodeURIComponent($.param(ob));
    setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
            url: 'http://example.world/mobile/index.php/welcome/my_trade_details',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);

            $('#started_at').html(data.trade_start);
            $('#ended_at').html(data.trade_end);
            $('#my_trade_is').html(data.trade_direction);
            $('#result_is').html(data.trade_result);
            $('#trade_status').html(data.trade_status);
            $('#concurrency').html(data.trade_concurrency);
            $('#amount').html(data.trade_amount);
            $('#etherum_contract_number').html(data.etherum_contract_number);
            },
            error: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
            if(typeof data === 'object'){
            var data = 'No Internet Connection Detected';
            }    
            }
        });
    }, 5 * 1000);
```

And this is the Vue.js code:

```
<div v-if="trade_direction === 'up'">
  <i class="green material-icons">arrow_upward</i>
</div>
<div v-else>
  <i class="green material-icons">arrow_downward</i>
</div>
```

How can I define and pass the variable `trade_direction` between jQuery and Vue.js?

Comment: You can't just pass the variable from jQuery to Vue because Vue uses it's own scope for your variables.

I would recommend to transfer your jQuery-Code to your Vue-Component (which also makes more sense).

Comment: Okay thanks. I shall write a component for that.